# How to override the color defined in css?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this style class it's create red rectange in the view:

```
.tag-template .left-panel { 
  width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
   background: red;
   vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Here how I use the class in view template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tag-template">
  <div class="tag-template">
    <div class="left-panel">          
    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
      <span>{{$getDisplayText()}}</span>
      <a class="remove-button" ng-click="$removeTag()">&#10006;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

At some point I want to override the color defined in css `.tag-template .left-panel` and change color to be green.

Any idea how can I change the color defined in css in the view using ng-style for examle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-style to change color like myStyle can be your expression

```
  <div class="left-panel" ng-style="myStyle"></div>
```

**or**

```
 <div class="left-panel" ng-style="{color:'green'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My I suggest you keep logic in your markup and styles in your CSS, it will make code easier to read and maintenance well structured.

*Note, no space between `.left-panel.left-panel-color`*

CSS

```
.tag-template .left-panel.left-panel-color { 
   color: green;    
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="left-panel left-panel-color">
</div>
```

Comment: I get color from database.I need it dynamic

Comment: @Michael Then inline styling most likely is the way in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override by pure css method:
old code:

```
<div class="left-panel">
```

new code:

```
<div class="left-panel" style="color:green";>
```